# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 18 (char 17) with not finding any fault

Tags: python, json

Maybe you know a bit more than I about those Decode Errors, but I got this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\main.commands.py", line 91, in on_message
    await XPRole.save_last_msg(fb)
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\New_Functions\XPRole.py", line 59, in save_last_msg
    jsonhandle.update("last_message", lastmsg, "lastmsg")
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\Functions\jsonhandle.py", line 56, in update
    _load(jsonfile)
  File "C:\Users\FlexGames\Desktop\Programming\Discord Bot\New Bot\Functions\jsonhandle.py", line 73, in _load
    lmsgjson = json.load(lmsgload)
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Try Me Btch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 18 (char 17)
```

My code where the error is:

```
elif jsonfile == "lastmsg":
    global lmsgjson
    with open("C:/Users/FlexGames/Desktop/Programming/Discord Bot/New Bot/lastmsg.json", "r") as lmsgload:
        lmsgjson = json.load(lmsgload)
```

I have no clue what it could be as I also tried to remove the complete path so only going with "lastmsg.json" but I got the same error.

Comment: One possibility is that your `lastmsg.json` file contains invalid JSON.  Take a look at the contents of that file.  Alternatively, as you're using Windows, maybe the file needs to be opened with `encoding="utf-8"`.

Comment: you can validate your json on jsonlint.com, in case there is any issue with json, you will be able to catch it.

Comment: @LukeWoodward it was the invalid JSON. I thought you could write just nothing behind the ":" and it would be nothing, but.. well, it isn't like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

You cannot do your file like

```
{"whatever": }
```

Comment: If you want an empty value you can use `null` (`None` in python)